# Difficult region for content in WPF

Tags: wpf, path, polygon

I need to make the polygon of arbitrary shape in which to draw content, such as a picture.
And the polygon is such that one part is tied, the other part must depend on the size of its parent container.

It is necessary to make a XAML WPF.
So far, nothing I can think of.
Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you define arbitrary.  There is a shape space.  Examples in both XAML and code behind.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx.   You will need to refer to actualwidth and actualheight in you code behind to get the rendered size of the container.  You might start with just drawing a diagonal line to figure out size then then step up to a polygon.  You probably want to use a canvas as you container.

Answer (score 0):

ОК. I got the following

**C# code:**

```
private void Grid_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundPathChange();
    }    

private void BackgroundPathChange()
        {    
            int heightDesign = 300;
            int widthDesign = 300;

            var separatorLine = new List<Point>(){
                                    new Point(20, 1.1666667),
                                    new Point(45.5, 110.99967),
                                    new Point(45.5, 187.49966),
                                    new Point(45.5, 237.49966),
                                    new Point(19.5, 296.49966),
                                    new Point(295.5, 295.49966),
                                    new Point(289.5, 0.49966663)
                                };

            rightBackgroundPath.Data = Geometry.Parse(
                string.Format("M{0},{1} L{2},{3} {4},{5} {6},{7} {8},{9} {10},{11} {12},{13}",
                              (int)separatorLine[0].X, (int)(separatorLine[0].Y * gridContainer.ActualHeight / heightDesign),
                              (int)separatorLine[1].X, (int)(separatorLine[1].Y * gridContainer.ActualHeight / heightDesign),
                              (int)separatorLine[2].X, (int)(separatorLine[2].Y * gridContainer.ActualHeight / heightDesign),
                              (int)separatorLine[3].X, (int)(separatorLine[3].Y * gridContainer.ActualHeight / heightDesign),
                              (int)separatorLine[4].X, (int)(separatorLine[4].Y * gridContainer.ActualHeight / heightDesign),

                              (int)(separatorLine[5].X * gridContainer.ActualWidth / widthDesign),
                              (int)(separatorLine[5].Y * gridContainer.ActualHeight / heightDesign),
                              (int)(separatorLine[6].X * gridContainer.ActualWidth / widthDesign),
                              (int)(separatorLine[6].Y * gridContainer.ActualHeight / heightDesign)
                    ));
        }
```

**XAML:**

```
<Grid SizeChanged="Grid_SizeChanged" x:Name="gridContainer">
    <Path
          x:Name="rightBackgroundPath"
        Data="M20,1 L44,110.99967 45.5,187.49966 45.5,237.49966 19.5,300 300,300 300,0" 
          Fill="Yellow" Stroke="Green"/>
</Grid>
```

Can somehow simplify this?

Comment: What part is too complex?  40 lines C# and 4 lines of XAML is not a lot of code.   Is it not working?   Looks like you are going to lose some precision with the int conversion.

Comment: Thanks. Type Int - only test, changed if required. I do not like big code C#.